# Average of all records

Tags: postgresql

I need to show the average of all records of a table, on each row.

```
Id    Value
1     3
2     1
3     4
4     2
```

The average is (3+1+4+2)/4 = 2.5

I want to get this:

```
Id    Value   Average
1     3       2.5
2     1       2.5
3     4       2.5
4     2       2.5
```

P.S.: I'm using PostgreSql 9.3, I can use windowing functions.

Comment: Using [analytical](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/899b1/1) function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL version, short and elegant:

```
SELECT Id, Value, AVG(Value) AS Average
FROM scores;
```

PostgreSQL version, not quite the same:

```
SELECT ID, Value, tblAvg.Average
FROM scores
INNER JOIN (SELECT AVG(Value) AS Average from scores) AS tblAvg ON 1=1
```

Comment: Hrm, this doesn't work on Postgres, but does on MySQL

Comment: Great!, your 2nd answer is what I need. Thank you.